# How to find 2.6.35 pae kernel for 10.04?

Tags: 10.04

I once found a website where I could download the pae kernels manually, but now I have been searching and can't come up with the site.

I just installed 10.04 and want the updated kernel now, so I don't have to re-config anything when a new kernel comes out.

Anyone can help?  Would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are refering to the mainline builds, you can find all instructions and warnings here

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds